# Stata 14 fails to start on RHEL 7.x, with “libpng12.so.0” error. How do I install libpng12?

Tags: rhel, software-installation, yum, shared-library

The proprietary software Stata version 14 breaks on RHEL 7.3. Stata says:

```
stata-se: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So my question is, how can I safely install and make this library available to Stata? (Apparently, the Stata GUI won't work perfectly even with the library, but the functionality will be available.)

Trying with `yum` gives an error:

```
Unable to locate package libpng12
```

`libpng` is already installed and up to date, and seems not to fit the need.

NOTE: This question was [ported over](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900506/stata-14-fails-to-start-on-ubuntu-16-10-with-libpng12-so-0-error-how-do-i-in/900914) from AskUbuntu, where my RedHat suggested solution was deleted and I was told to go elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Red Hat / Fedora / CentOS systems (corresponding to RHEL version 7.x), the RPM you need can be found [here](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/libpng12-1.2.50-10.el7.x86_64.rpm.html). I installed it using the RHEL 7.3 GUI.

`libpng12` is a legacy library. Stata needs to be updated in order to restore compatibility with the most up-to-date version of `libpng` (Stata is unlikely to move away from this dependency anytime soon).

Other potentially useful solutions can be found at the AskUbuntu link noted in the question.